# Splash activity with orientation support

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I want my splash activity to support both vertical and horizontal orientation.

The code for splash activity is as follows

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try{
                sleep(5000);    

            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent ARCActivityIntent = new Intent("com.ex.rc.LISTSCREEN");
                startActivity(ARCActivityIntent);// 
                finish();
            }
        }};

    timer.start();

    }

}
```

Code of splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_bg"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is - LISTSCREEN activity is re-created number of times the orientation is changed.

Help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having a similiar problem. I got it fixed. Here is the solution.
Create only one layout for splash screen, but create different images for `LANDSCAPE` and `PORTRAIT`. As you have only one layout i.e portrait, the activity would not be re-created. But background image would change providing the effect of orientation change.
Write down the following code in onCreate.

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);

splashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_img);

int orient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
if (orient == 0) {
         splashImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_portrait);
} else {
         splashImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_landscape);
}
```

Override `onConfigurationChanged` method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int orient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();
    if (orient == 0) {
        splashImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_portrait);
    } else {
        splashImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_landscape);
    }
}
```

SplashActivity in manifest should look like this

```
    <activity
        android:name="SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Also don't forget to add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to Splash activity description in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @muhammad-nabeel-arif thanks. +1 for your suggestion but i don't want to use onConfigurationChanged method and two different images. I want the single image to rotate on orientation change and i have made it. You can check it in eclipse. The only problem i want to avoid is the recreation of LISTSCREEN activity on orientation change.

Comment: Add android:screenOrientation="portrait" in splashActivity's Manifest. This will restrict orientation to  only landscape. so activity will not be re-created.

Comment: @MuhammadNabeelArif I don't want to do it either. Because then the image will not be rotated to landscape when i switch to landscape mode.

Comment: @sam,add 'android:configChanges="orientation"' in your manifest. But make sure you have splash_layout.xml in only one layout folder i.e res/layout/ but not in res/layout-port/ and res/layout-land/. In this way you will have only one layout which would be rotated to LANDSCAPE OR PORTRAIT, But will not re-drawn or re-created as there is a single xml layout.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

In Manifest: Change orientation to `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`

Remove any Oriantations from splash layouts e.g. `android:orientation="vertical"`

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.gr8ly.gr8lysymbolshortcutkeys.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```